# Segmentation Fault in C ,Breadth First Search

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to access directly into memory in c. I need that because my array size needed to be dynamic. There's the code block that includes Breadth-First Search Algorithm, where am i wrong?

```
int visited[h][w];
int parent[h][w][2]; // Width, Height, {x,y}
int d[] = {0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0};
int p[2];
int cell[2];
int *q = (int*)malloc(10000*sizeof(int));
int front = 0, rear = 0;
q[front++]=sPoint[0];
q[front++]=sPoint[1];

visited[sPoint[1]][sPoint[0]] = 1;
while ((front - rear) > 0) {
    p[0] = q[rear++]; // [0,1,5,6,7,8]
    p[1] = q[rear++];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cell[0] = d[i * 2] + p[0];
        cell[1] = d[i * 2 + 1] + p[1];
        if (cell[0] >= 0 && cell[0] < w && cell[1] >= 0 && cell[1] < h
                && visited[cell[1]][cell[0]] == 0 && isBlack(cell[0], cell[1]) != 1) {
            if(!(front <= sizeof(front)/sizeof(int) - 5))
            {
                q = (int*)realloc(q,1.75*front);
            }
            q[front++] = cell[0];
            q[front++] = cell[1];
            visited[cell[1]][cell[0]] = visited[p[1]][p[0]] + 1;
            parent[cell[1]][cell[0]][0] = p[0];
            parent[cell[1]][cell[0]][1] = p[1];
            if (cell[0] == ePoint[0] && cell[1] == ePoint[1]) {
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some tips: the size/types of `parent` and `sPoint` are not included. Don't cast the malloc.  I would use parenthesis in the `if`'s (i.e. `...if ((cell[0] >= 0) && (cell[0] < w)...`). What is the point of `sizeof(front)/sizeof(int)` ? And why are you comparing ((`unsigned`)1-5) with `int`?.  `realloc` expects a `size_t`, not a decimal. Arrays as index of arrays are hard to manage, because it is too easy to request a value out of the array. I hardly recommend you to debug your code, step by step, to find out the error(s) in the code.

Comment: @GökberkAçıkgöz ??? Why is there a realloc with "1.75 * front" as size ?

Comment: @JoseFelipe Using useless parenthesis in the if (because all of test are &&) will only add difficulty to reading. A part from the fact that the if is long, there's nothing wrong.

Comment: @Tom's that is the reason why I said "I would..". Both are correct and `&&` is primary-expression, but in terms of readability, I am agree with this answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201175/should-i-use-parentheses-in-logical-statements-even-where-not-necessary

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert an appropriate horizontal space inside parens, inside braces, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators  2) separate code blocks `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  3) variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both) 4) honor the right page margin (usually column 72 or 80)

Comment: when calling C library functions, for instance: `malloc()`, always check the returned value for errors

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] otherwise the question is 'off topic' and the 'close' votes will quickly accumulate.

Comment: the posted code fails to declare the variable `found` and is not even a complete function.

Comment: thank you @user3629249. found is a global variable, i didn't send it to here.